# Button in form tag on click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Body Tag**

```
<div id="stage1">
    <form id="form1" method="post">
        <button id="sm1" type="submit" class="button" onclick="Result(msg);"><span>GO – SM1</span></button>
        <div id="sm2">GO – SM2</div>
    </form>
    <button id="sm3"type="submit" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"> GO – SM3</button>
</div>
<div id="stage2" hidden="">
    HELLO WORLD
</div>
```

**Script Tag**

```
<script> 
    function sleep (time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sm1").click(function(){
            $("#stage1").fadeOut(600);
            sleep(700).then(() => {
                $("#stage2").fadeIn(600);
            });
        });
    });   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sm2").click(function(){
            $("#stage1").fadeOut(600);
            sleep(700).then(() => {
                $("#stage2").fadeIn(600);
            });
        });
    });   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sm3").click(function(){
            $("#stage1").fadeOut(600);
            sleep(700).then(() => {
                $("#stage2").fadeIn(600);
            });
        });
    });   
</script>
```

**Problem**

When I click the button GO – SM1, nothing happen

but when I click in area of DIV tag GO – SM2, stage1 is disappear and stage2 is appear

also I click another button outer form tag GO – SM3,  stage1 is disappear and stage2 is appear too.

**How**

to click on the button GO – SM1 then stage1 is disappear and stage2 is appear like I click on GO – SM2 and GO – SM3

Comment: Hit F12, look at your console.

Comment: why you have multiple document.ready() ?

Comment: @want2learn because I show in 3 areas sm1, sm2 and sm3. sm2 and sm3 work fine but not sm1 T_T

Comment: @AsiaDep you don't need to have multiple document ready function which makes your code clumsy. Back to your question did you follow what Richard have in the answer

Comment: @want2learn Yes I do and it still doesn't work for ID sm1 I think maybe It's in form tag then I guess $("#sm1") is wrong for calling ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok step one remove the onclick change types to button not submit.

```
<div id="stage1">
    <form id="form1" method="post">
        <button id="sm1" type="button" class="button"><span>GO – SM1</span></button>
        <div id="sm2">GO – SM2</div>
    </form>
    <button id="sm3"type="button" class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"> GO – SM3</button>
</div>
<div id="stage2" hidden="">
    HELLO WORLD
</div>
```

Step 2 clean this up a bit

```
<script> 
    function sleep (time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sm1").click(function(){
            $("#stage1").fadeOut(600);
            sleep(700).then(() => {
                $("#stage2").fadeIn(600);
            });
        });

        $("#sm2").click(function(){
            $("#stage1").fadeOut(600);
            sleep(700).then(() => {
                $("#stage2").fadeIn(600);
            });
        });

        $("#sm3").click(function(){
            $("#stage1").fadeOut(600);
            sleep(700).then(() => {
                $("#stage2").fadeIn(600);
            });
        });

    });   

</script>
```

That should help.

Comment: I deleted the onclick but It didn't work It still nothing happen T_T

Comment: Change the types to button?

Comment: I changed the button type to the input type 'submit' (id = 'sm1' in the form tag) ...and nothing happen too...

Comment: I try few minute ago it still doesn't work for sm1 T_T (try all new your code, delete type='submit' and change button tag to input tag) I think something wrong because it's in form tag? if it is outside tag there is no problem so maybe $("#sm1") is a problem for calling ?.

Comment: @AsiaDep try $("#sm1").on("click" , "#stage1",function(){

Comment: @want2learn I tried $("#sm1").on("click" , "#stage1",function(){ and nothing happen so....... I tried $("#sm2").on("click" , "#stage1",function(){ and $("#sm3").on("click" , "#stage1",function(){ It doesn't work for all sm1, sm2 and sm3

Comment: Your click event handler is perfectly fine. It has some issue with your Promise.